Should copper tubes be sealed when removing aircons?
There are about 75 feet of copper tubes for split type aircons in a building. If the aircon would be removed. Should you seal the copper tubes?
If not, how long can it remain unsealed before a new aircon is installed by another tenant?
If the copper tubes should be sealed, how do you seal it? Just twist the end with pliers or put putty in the hole? What is the standard procedure?

I’m voting to close this question because it is about work in a commercial building.

The question seems perfectly applicable to residential situations as well. With heat pumps ever more commonly replacing conventional HVAC systems it's a likely scenario. Also, the presence of a tenant does not mean it's a commercial building. It could be a duplex in which I reside.

Yes the lines should be sealed to prevent any debris or moisture from getting in.  While the dryer will need to be changed anyway and the lines evacuated with a pump before refilling with new refrigerant, excess moisture and debris will impede that process.
I would not recommend putty, use pliers and bend the end over on itself creating a kink.  Or if you have the tools, solder a cap onto the ends.

Yes, you want to keep debris and moisture out of the pipes. Just corking the ends with foam ear plugs or capping them with rubber covers, and also keeping them out of the rain, is enough.

where will I get the exact foam ear plugs or rubber covers?

Just type "rubber tube end cover"  or "foam ear plugs" into a search engine.  auto parts / hardware / pharmacy etc...

great idea, i asked chatgpt too what they are.
